# npm run tests before build

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently discovered the `npm version [major|minor|patch]` command to automatically bump the package version number and commit the changes. This was a magical little discovery.

Is it possible to run tests prior to the bump & git commit with npm? Trying to avoid having to write a bash script.

I can't find anything on google or stack search "npm version ....." matches too many unrelated results. And there is no info about testing in the docs [npm-version](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-version.html)

I was begging to write a script before this discovery. To test, bump version, then git commit.

I'm using karma, package.json contains

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma run"
}
```

While testing the npm version command I added a failing test

```
it("force fail",function(){
    expect(true).toEqual(1);
});
```

So `karma run` and `npm test` both result in a failed test run. I was hoping this would stop the version patch, but no luck. I managed to bump and commit with failing tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding them to `scripts` could work, though I really would recommend just defining a function in your shell’s runtime configuration.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "karma run",
    "major": "karma run && npm version major && git commit",
    "minor": "karma run && npm version minor && git commit",
    "patch": "karma run && npm version patch && git commit"
}
```

Comment: npm version is already handling the git commit, and that command wouldn't check for passed tests before continuing to bump the version. I want to test for successful test run before continuing.

Comment: @Lex: That’s what `&&` does. Or at least it’s what it ought to do; if it doesn’t, `karma` is doing its job wrong.

Comment: Sorry you're right, it is failing or passing based on `karma run` fail or pass (for both karma run & npm test). I would have thought putting build scripts/commands in the run time bad practice, for a team or open source projects. It is a good idea though, which solves the immediate requirement. I'm gonna go do that :) `alias npmpatch='npm test && npm version patch'`. I was hoping there was a mystical flag in the npm command.